# Best way to find references for statements in the thesis

Tags: citations, thesis

I am struggling finding proper references for the known facts that are mentioned in my thesis.

For example: foundation of Cartesian coordinate system introduced the grid system for data visualization techniques.

How can I possibly find a reference to support that claim?

What is your best method for finding references?

Comment: You might be able to turn this into a good question if you can edit it to be more specific.  As it is, there's no right answer to this.

Comment: @user1449456: I fail to parse your example statement.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I think the answer the OP needs would involve finding out who invented the Cartesian coordinate system. Hint: all the required pointers are already there >:-)

Answer (score 3):

Although the question is a bit vague, I try to give you an answer from my experience. There are often statements that you heard somewhere or which are "obviously" true, but you need a reference.

My best bet is to search google scholar for a variety of different combinations of the terms or suspected authors. If you find some source stating the claim (or something similar) you can often go back through the chain of citations to find a more accurate and reliable source.

Depending on the subject, searching google books is also helpful.

Comment: Another good starting point can be the references section of the relevant Wikipedia page (treading with caution of course).

Answer (score 0):

"Common knowledge" are usually not referenced. Yet, what is or is not common knowledge is field- or even individual-dependent. A little investigation may help: look at some journals you think would be a potential home of your article, and learn about their points of view on common knowledge. Talking to your supervisors will also be a good method.

And just a side comments: I am not sure if I understand your example statement and if other problematic statements are like this you may want to talk this through with someone. The coordinate system was meant to project data/information, and one of the manifestations looks like a rectangular grid. But why does it have to be "introduced" again to data visualization when the means and motive were pretty much identical? Be it on a sheepskin map or on a hi-def flat screen, data projection is still data projection. (tl; dr: I humbly think that example statement is redundant. But I am not an expert in this field, sorry if this sounds naive or offensive.)